# How does Kylo Ren know?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

How does Kylo Ren know about Rey's parents?

In The Last Jedi, Kylo Ren tells Rey that

> she already knew the truth about her parents: that they were drunks who sold her off into slavery.

How does he know this?

Comment: Please try to avoid cross-posting the exact same question to multiple sites at once. If you want to move a question over to a different site, feel free to flag it as such. Alternatively, if you don't get a satisfying answer after some time, you can try reasking it, maybe tailored to the specific community.

Comment: Gonna disagree that is the "exact same question," as one is 'Is he right?' and the other is 'How does he know?' I asked the former on SciFi for a reason, and the latter here for a separate reason. I respect the Hand of the Mod, but with zero close votes and 40 minutes of active time, I don't see the negative impact here.

Comment: It *seemed* pretty much like the exact same question to me, given that the other one basically asks how he would know that. If it isn't, feel free to clarify that in the question. You don't have to "respect the Hand of the Mod" if you have genuine reservations against any actions. That's why [on hold] questions are there to get improved into reopenability. However, *if* it is the same question, then immediate cross-posting is generally discouraged across SE.

Comment: I think this is a valid question. It assumes that Kylo is telling the truth, but it's worth asking how he got there - did he read Rey's mind? Or somehow see the past through the Force?